# Any questions for the Stack Exchange VP of Community?

Tags: discussion

Jojek, Datageist, and I have been asked if we want to meet with the Stack Exchange VP of Community, [Philippe.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe)

Does anyone have any questions for Philippe?